# How to query unmapped types beautiful, with EF8

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, .net-core

I am using Entity Framework 8 and OracleDB. My example statement below is simple, but it can be much more complex.

I am using `SqlQuery()` to load the result into a record type.

The columns of the statement and the properties of the record must match, so I need to use aliases.
I usually use string interpolation for these aliases.
`SqlQuery()` uses string interpolation to parameterize the query.

Combining both is difficult, because aliases are interpreted as SQL parameters.

**These are my requirements:**

1. Using aliases
2. Using SQL parameters
3. A nice, readable **and maintainable** statement in code.

This ist my sample project:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

Func<string, string> sq = (x) => $"\"{(x)}\""; //helper to surround with quotes

//------------------
// <-- add option here
// ----------------

public record DbVersion(string BannerName, string FullBannerName);
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {       
        var con = "xxxxx";
        optionsBuilder.UseOracle(con);
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); }));
    }
}
```

**Option 1**

```
Console.WriteLine(
    dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbVersion>(
        $""" select BANNER "BannerName", BANNER_FULL "FullBannerName" from V$VERSION where 1 = {1} """
    ).Single()
);
```

*Result log:*

```
Executed DbCommand (79ms) [Parameters=[p0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
      SELECT "d"."BannerName", "d"."FullBannerName"
      FROM (
           select BANNER "BannerName", BANNER_FULL "FullBannerName" from V$VERSION where 1 = :p0
      ) "d"
```

It uses SQL parameter but the property name is "hiding" in a string. This is problamatic while refactoring.

**Option 2**

```
Console.WriteLine(
    dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbVersion>(
        FormattableStringFactory.Create(
            $" select BANNER {sq(nameof(DbVersion.BannerName))}, BANNER_FULL {sq(nameof(DbVersion.FullBannerName))} from V$VERSION where 1 = {1} ")
    ).Single()
);
```

*Result log:*

```
Executed DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
  SELECT "d"."BannerName", "d"."FullBannerName"
  FROM (
       select BANNER "BannerName", BANNER_FULL "FullBannerName" from V$VERSION where 1 = 1
  ) "d"
```

It uses nameof(), so the alias has always the correct spelling, but uses no SQL parameter.

**Option 3**

```
var select = $" select BANNER {sq(nameof(DbVersion.BannerName))}, BANNER_FULL {sq(nameof(DbVersion.FullBannerName))} "; //for aliases
FormattableString fs2 = $" from v$version where 1 = {1}"; //for SQL parameter

Console.WriteLine(
    dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbVersion>(
        FormattableStringFactory.Create(select + fs2.Format, fs2.GetArguments())
    ).Single()
);
```

*Result log:*

```
Executed DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[p0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
  SELECT "d"."BannerName", "d"."FullBannerName"
  FROM (
       select BANNER "BannerName", BANNER_FULL "FullBannerName"  from v$version where 1 = :p0
  ) "d"
```

It uses nameof() and uses SQL parameter, but the statement is split into several different variables.

**Option 4**

```
Console.WriteLine( dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<DbVersion>(
   $" select BANNER {sq(nameof(DbVersion.BannerName))}, BANNER_FULL {sq(nameof(DbVersion.FullBannerName))} " + " from V$VERSION where 1 = {0} ",
   1
   ).Single()
);
```

*Result log:*

```
Executed DbCommand (20ms) [Parameters=[p0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
  SELECT "d"."BannerName", "d"."FullBannerName"
  FROM (
       select BANNER "BannerName", BANNER_FULL "FullBannerName"  from V$VERSION where 1 = :p0
  ) "d"
```

It using SqlQueryRaw, in this case I have to pass SQL parameters as arguments on my own. This is problematic when the argument list become very large in complex statements.

**Option 5**

```
Console.WriteLine(
  dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbVersion>(
      $" select BANNER {sq(nameof(DbVersion.BannerName))}, BANNER_FULL {sq(nameof(DbVersion.FullBannerName))} from V$VERSION where 1 = {1} "
  ).Single()
);
```

*Result log:*

```
Failed executing DbCommand (202ms) [Parameters=[p0='?' (Size = 2000), p1='?' (Size = 2000), p2='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
      SELECT "d"."BannerName", "d"."FullBannerName"
      FROM (
           select BANNER :p0, BANNER_FULL :p1 from V$VERSION where 1 = :p2
      ) "d"
```

It failed because aliases are interpreted as SQL parameters.

I would write my statement like in `2` or `5`, but both cannot be used.

Does anyone know a better solution. I don't like any of my solutions.